# Xcode pain, syntax highlight broken

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa, documentation

I've had problems with Xcode 4 (4.3.1 - 4E1019).

After a few hours maybe less, my code isn't highlighting correctly, it seems Xcode loses all sense of Cocoa and I end up with the example screenshot, I can't jump to methods (by clicking on a method holding down cmd key) - this should work as expected and it doesn't even work for the Cocoa base classes.

The only way I've found to sort this out is to go to Organizer > Project and delete the projects derived data, then Quit and relaunch Xcode, but it's not long before it goes wrong again.

Has anyone else had this problem ? It's really slowing me down. If anyone has any tips, that would be great.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Look at this it can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138047/xcode-code-loses-syntax-coloring

Comment: Sometimes cleaning the project, closing and restarting Xcode solves this issue - atleast for me.

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10245076/123632 to a similar question for 100% guaranteed solution to this problem!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Justin Boo pointed me to the best thread and although there are many votes and answers, the user who asked that question seems to have abandoned stack overflow.

I won't attempt to duplicate the best answer other then resume in a paragraph:

Xcode got confused with all my common headers declared in the **.pch file**, and the setting "**Precompile Prefix Header**" in Build Settings meant that Xcode was getting into some internal conflicts due to recursive imports of frameworks. **So change that setting to NO**.

So to keep things tidy, here's a link to the true answer that had me in a headlock: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6033009/662605