# CSS Syntax Coloring Not Working in Xcode 4.4.1

Tags: css, xcode

I recently upgraded Xcode to version 4.4.1, and now, CSS files don't take on the default syntax coloring associated with CSS files.  A dash appears next to the "None" option under Editor | Syntax coloring.  I have to manually check off the CSS option under Syntax coloring to associate colored syntax with CSS.

A last note: I don't use Xcode as an IDE, I use it as a text editor.  All other languages I work in take on syntax coloring without a problem; this issue applies only to CSS.

Comment: Did you try "none" in lower case ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Xcode the same way and I have it installed on two systems: Lion and Mountain Lion. The program's version is equally (4.6). So I found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784175/issue-with-code-autocompletion-syntax-highlighting-in-xcode-4-x/10245076#10245076), especially this:

> First, Make sure Xcode is closed, then turn up the indexer warning message level by entering in the Terminal:  **defaults write
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexingClangInvocationLogLevel 3**

And the interesting thing is that those solution completely solved my problem in Mountain Lion but didn't help in Lion.