# Syntax not highlighted in Xcode

Tags: xcode, syntax-highlighting

The rest of my syntax is highlighted, but when I declare an `@property` for `UIDocumentManager`, it doesn't highlight. I linked Core Data, and I dont see any other reason for it to not highlight. Help Please?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRpcF.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO3PD.png]

*edit* it compiles without errors, and I have restarted it multiple times

Comment: It compiles, doesn't it?

Comment: Is the `UIDocumentManager` not highlighting or `@property`? Have you tried restarting XCode?

Comment: Yes to both of the above.

Comment: Did you try changing themes in preferences? Maybe your theme is broken...

Comment: that didnt work either

Comment: You sure `UIManagedDocument` isn't in UIKit?

Comment: i'm pretty sure, and even if it was, it is linked and it still isn't highlighted

Comment: Perhaps you have some invisible characters in that line? Perhaps delete the line and rewrite it from scratch.

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784175/issue-with-code-autocompletion-syntax-highlighting-in-xcode-4-x, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138047/xcode-code-loses-syntax-coloring

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>`

If that doesn't work;

Go to the Organizer choose the Projects mode. Select your project and then for the project's Derived Data click Delete.  I think this clears the index.

Comment: I had this happen to me and it irritated the life out of me for a while.  Eventually, it just started working.

Comment: I can assure you I am also irritated. Let's hope it works soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have had syntax highlighting break on Xcode several times. Usually it can be fixed by going into Organizer and selecting your project and "Delete Derived Data", then restarting Xcode.