# XCode 6 figure out why indexing hangs

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autocomplete, indexer

I'm trying to get the dreaded "Indexing | Processing files" progress bar to finish, so I can have autocomplete an go-to-definition work.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784175/issue-with-code-autocompletion-syntax-highlighting-in-xcode-4-x) references that it might be possible to get the indexer to output where it's getting stuck, but it references old features of XCode that seem to be gone.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782721/xcode-beta-3-swift-indexing-forever) mentions killing processes to force the indexer to spit out an error, but it hasn't worked and killing processes seems like an unstable solution at best.

Essentially, I know that the Swift compiler/indexer is getting hung up on some line of code somewhere, and is disabling autocomplete until it finishes.  I'd like to know where that line of code is so I can change it/take it out.

How can I get a more verbose Indexer output?

Comment: Not sure how to get a more verbose output, but have you tried deleting your derived data and indexing again?

Comment: Normally the usual routine "Delete Derived Data" -> "Clean" -> "Restart XCode" fixes autocomplete temporarily, but this time Indexing has been broken for a few days now, nothing I've tried works.